# ConEmu/Cygwin: 'ls -ls' command line does not return an aligned output

Tags: format, cygwin, ls, conemu

I've installed **Cygwin v3.1.2 (0.340/5/3)** and **ConEmu v20191012 (64bits)**

When I run the command line below

```
c:\temp>ls -ls
total 0
       0 -rw-rw-r--+ 1 me None 0 Jan  5 12:40 fileA
                                                   0 -rw-rw-r--+ 1 me None 0 Jan  5 12:40 fileB
                                                                                               0 -rw-rw-r--+ 1 me None 0 Jan  5 12:40 fileC
```

I don't get the directory items aligned. But if I perform same action on another computer with **Cygwin  2.11.1 (0.329/5/3)** and **ConEmu v20191012 (64bits)**, I'll get the expected result, as it's shown next:

```
$ ls -ls
total 0
0 -rwxrwx---+ 1 me UK+Group(513) 0 Jan  5 12:41 fileA
0 -rwxrwx---+ 1 me UK+Group(513) 0 Jan  5 12:41 fileB
0 -rwxrwx---+ 1 me UL+Group(513) 0 Jan  5 12:41 fileC
```

Any idea about how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: no solution for the time being https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2020-01/msg00003.html

Comment: Thnkas @matzeri !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I've downloaded CyWwin 3.1.7, the issue does not exist anymore.
Thanks!